# How do I stub a method call followed by hash look up?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec3

I have the following:

```
request.env['HTTP_REFERER']
```

and want to stub the `request.env` only when it is followed by the hash look up.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Why do you feel that `request.env` is method, and not a `Hash`?

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter right? It's return value is a hash. So it really is how do you stub a hash look up.

Comment: `request.env` is compelled to return an object if you want that notation to work, but it's not compelled to do any work. When that object has its `[]` method called that's when you need to stub. Are you asking for a stub that returns a stub on-demand?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to stub `#[]` method of request.env. One way to do so is to define a singleton method in request.env using `define_singleton_method` and override the original `#[]` method.

```
[19] pry(main)> env = { a: 1 } # or whatever object of a class that has #[]
=> {:a=>1}
[20] pry(main)> env[:a]
=> 1
[21] pry(main)> env.size
=> 2
[22] pry(main)> env.define_singleton_method(:[]) { |key| key.upcase }
=> :[]
[23] pry(main)> env[:a]
=> :A
[24] pry(main)> env.size
=> 2
[25] pry(main)> env.define_singleton_method(:[]) { |key| key == 'HTTP_REFERER' ? 'http://example.com' : super(key) }
=> :[]
[26] pry(main)> env[:a]
=> 1
[27] pry(main)> env['HTTP_REFERER']
=> "http://example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RSpec.describe Hash do
  subject { described_class.new(foo: :bar) }

  it "returns the value via #[]" do
    expect(subject).to receive("[]").with(:foo)
    subject[:foo]
  end
end
```

In Ruby, `hash[:foo]` is just syntactic sugar. It's identical to calling the method `[]` with the argument `:foo` on the hash:

```
hash = { foo: :bar }
#=> {:foo=>:bar}
hash.public_send("[]", :foo)
#=> :bar
```